# Erro compilacao Unit JV de D2010 p/ Tokyo

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Estou tentando compilar um sistema que foi desenvolvido em D7, mas esta rodando no D2010, agora estamos convertendo para o Tokyo, quando tento compilar o sistema obtenho a seguinte msg de erro:

```
C:\Delphi\componentes\jedi\jvcl\jvcl\common;C:\Delphi\componentes\jedi\jvcl\jvcl\Resources;C:\Delphi\componentes\jedi\jvcl\jvcl\run 
--default-namespace:gestac -K00400000 -GD -NBC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Dcp 
-NHC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\hpp\Win32 -NOdcu   myproject.dpr   
[dcc32 Error] JvThemes.pas(814): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TButtonStyle'
[dcc32 Fatal Error] JvThemes.pas(855): F2613 Unit 'JclSysInfo' not found.
```

A instalação do JVCL foi feita "do zero" e não apresentou nehum erro.

Comment: O que tem de errado na minha pergunta para ser negativada?, poderiam me explicar que erro cometi?

Comment: Consulte no "Library Path" da IDE (Tools, Options, Library, Library Path) se os diretórios dos arquivos do Jedi estão todos lá e são diretórios válidos.

Comment: Obrigado @LGregianin, era isso mesmo, mas é duro para fazer a migração heim? Nesse caso a Instalação do JVCL não adiciona tudo que é necessario no libpath, é preciso rodar varias vezes o sistema e ir adicionando. :-)